# Power and Sample Size Estimation for Logistic Regression (Mixed) Models

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, glmm, statistical-power

I am working on designing a study based on some initial pilot data and would like to conduct a sample size estimation. I have previously used `simr` with linear mixed effects models. In this case, I think a logistic (glm) or logistic mixed model (glmer) are more appropriate, but am unsure if I am approaching things correctly/defensibly.

I have data from 29 subjects with two continuous predictors (scores on two assessment), a binary outcome of event occurrence in the last 12 months, and the count of events in the last 12 months.

Example data:

```
    Data <- structure(list(Subject = 1:29, Score = c(25, 11.7, 11.7, 43.3, 
            25, 38.3, 31.7, 35, 30, 36.7, 16.7, 36.7, 11.7, 36.7, 13.3, 96.7, 
            10, 20, 25, 36.7, 45, 51.7, 68.3, 38.3, 18.3, 5, 18.3, 20, 33.3), 
            Score1 = c(100L, 100L, 100L, 80L, 100L, 100L, 80L, 90L, 100L, 
            60L, 100L, 90L, 90L, 100L, 100L, 70L, 100L, 90L, 100L, 40L, 100L, 
            40L, 10L, 80L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 90L, 100L), Count = c(0, 0, 
            2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 4, 3, 2, 12, 
            1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), Bin = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
            0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)), 
           class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
          -29L), .Names = c("Subject", "Score", "Score1", "Count", "Bin"))
```

I have tried I have tried poisson and binomial logistic and logistic mixed models:

```
# Logistic models
Mod1 <- glm(Count ~ Score + Score1, family = "poisson", data = Data)
Mod2 <- glm(Bin ~ Score + Score1, family = "binomial"(link = logit), data = Data)

# Logistic mixed models
Mod3 <- glmer(Count ~ Score + Score1 + (1|Subject), family = "poisson", data = Data)
Mod4 <- glmer(Bin ~ Score + Score1 + (1|Subject), family = "binomial"(link = logit), data = Data)
```

I have tried some estimating power using `powerSim` in the `simr` package:

```
powerSim(Mod1, nsim = 100)
Power for predictor 'Score', (95% confidence interval):
       5.10% ( 3.82,  6.65)

Test: z-test

Based on 1000 simulations, (0 warnings, 0 errors)
alpha = 0.05, nrow = 29

powerSim(Mod2)
Power for predictor 'Score', (95% confidence interval)
       3.20% ( 2.20,  4.49)

Test: z-test

Based on 1000 simulations, (0 warnings, 0 errors)
alpha = 0.05, nrow = 29 

powerSim(Mod3)
Power for predictor 'Score', (95% confidence interval):
       4.60% ( 3.39,  6.09)

Test: z-test
      Effect size for Score is 9.1e-05

Based on 1000 simulations, (11 warnings, 0 errors)
alpha = 0.05, nrow = 29

powerSim(Mod4)
Power for predictor 'Score', (95% confidence interval):
       1.70% ( 0.99,  2.71)

Test: z-test
      Effect size for Score is -0.0038

Based on 1000 simulations, (715 warnings, 1 error)
alpha = 0.05, nrow = 29
```

Power is low, so I'd like to know how much larger the sample should be to get closer to 80%.

My first question is whether a standard (`glm`) is more appropriate than a mixed (`glmer`) approach?

I've seen some conflicting views on the appropriateness and risk of over-fitting with single observation groupings.

My second questions is how to go about extending the models with the `extend` function in `simr`.

How do I extend the model to estimate the effects of more subjects?

I have tried the following for the standard (`glm`) models:

```
powerCurve(extend(Mod1, along = "Score", n = 100))
Power for predictor 'Score', (95% confidence interval),
by largest value of Score:
      3:  0.00% ( 0.00,  0.37) - 7 rows
     14:  2.70% ( 1.79,  3.90) - 23 rows
     25:  5.40% ( 4.08,  6.99) - 40 rows
     35:  4.70% ( 3.47,  6.20) - 54 rows
     46:  4.50% ( 3.30,  5.98) - 74 rows
     57:  3.50% ( 2.45,  4.83) - 87 rows
     68:  4.20% ( 3.04,  5.64) - 106 rows
     78:  3.60% ( 2.53,  4.95) - 122 rows
     89:  3.70% ( 2.62,  5.06) - 138 rows
    100:  4.50% ( 3.30,  5.98) - 155 rows

powerCurve(extend(Mod2, along = "Score", n = 100))
Power for predictor 'Score', (95% confidence interval),
by largest value of Score:
      3:  0.00% ( 0.00,  0.37) - 7 rows
     14:  3.80% ( 2.70,  5.18) - 23 rows
     25:  5.80% ( 4.43,  7.43) - 40 rows
     35:  5.60% ( 4.26,  7.21) - 54 rows
     46:  4.90% ( 3.65,  6.43) - 74 rows
     57:  5.80% ( 4.43,  7.43) - 87 rows
     68:  7.90% ( 6.30,  9.75) - 106 rows
     78:  8.40% ( 6.76, 10.29) - 122 rows
     89: 10.50% ( 8.67, 12.57) - 138 rows
    100: 10.40% ( 8.58, 12.46) - 155 rows
```

These results don't make sense to me, since each row represents an observation and the model has one observation per subject. The output goes to 155 rows rather than 100. How do I simulate the effects of adding more subjects? Am I going about this all wrong?

For the mixed (`glmer`) models, I got rank-deficiency errors during simulation, so I dropped "Score1" and used:

```
Mod5 <- glmer(Count ~ Score + (1|Subject), family = "poisson", data = Data)

powerCurve(extend(Mod5, along = "Subject", n = 100), along = "Subject)
Power for predictor 'Score', (95% confidence interval),
by largest value of Subject:
      3:  0.60% ( 0.22,  1.30) - 3 rows
     14:  9.00% ( 7.30, 10.95) - 14 rows
     25: 60.70% (57.59, 63.74) - 25 rows
     35: 64.90% (61.85, 67.86) - 35 rows
     46: 81.10% (78.53, 83.48) - 46 rows
     57: 86.50% (84.22, 88.56) - 57 rows
     68: 87.50% (85.29, 89.49) - 68 rows
     78: 94.30% (92.68, 95.65) - 78 rows
     89: 96.60% (95.28, 97.63) - 89 rows
    100: 96.60% (95.28, 97.63) - 100 rows

Mod6 <- glmer(Bin ~ Score + (1|Subject), family = "binomial"(link = logit, data = Data)

powerCurve(extend(Mod6, along = "Subject", n = 100), along = "Subject")
Power for predictor 'Score', (95% confidence interval),
by largest value of Subject:
      3:  0.00% ( 0.00,  0.37) - 3 rows
     14:  1.10% ( 0.55,  1.96) - 14 rows
     25:  2.10% ( 1.30,  3.19) - 25 rows
     35:  2.60% ( 1.71,  3.79) - 35 rows
     46:  6.20% ( 4.79,  7.88) - 46 rows
     57: 12.70% (10.70, 14.92) - 57 rows
     68: 16.10% (13.87, 18.53) - 68 rows
     78: 20.50% (18.04, 23.14) - 78 rows
     89: 27.00% (24.27, 29.87) - 89 rows
    100: 29.90% (27.08, 32.84) - 100 rows
```

These look more like what I'd expect. But, I had to drop one of the predictors to get it run and more importantly I'm unsure about whether or not a mixed model is appropriate and/or defensible.